# Resources for solving Euclidean geometry problems using symmetries

Tags: geometry, reference-request, problem-solving, book-recommendation, symmetry

I know a number of books that treat geometry from the viewpoint of transformations/symmetries. However, very few of them actually teach someone to solve Euclidean geometry problems using said symmetries.

Are there any books who fill this gap? Here is [an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472604/how-can-the-angle-be-found-in-this-triangle) of problem solved using symmetry.

Comment: You might have seen this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842915/a-modern-alternative-to-euclidean-geometry?rq=1, where you might find something by digging into the references in the comments by Mauro Allegranza. But it I don't know if what you want exists. Modern treatments of synthetic Euclidean geometry seem to be heavily influenced by Hilbert who focussed not so much on the native symmetry arguments in Euclid's Elements.

Answer (score 1):

See [*Geometric Transformations I, II, III, IV*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883856085) by Yaglom.